# How to get an Azure pipeline for Go to work

Tags: azure, go, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The default .yaml file provided by the ADO pipeline fails.  There's been an issue open for over a year on it and the problem still exists.

I tried this .yaml file from [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/go?view=azure-devops&tabs=go-current) but it fails with the error below.  Does someone have a .yaml file that works for a Go pipeline in Azure DevOps?

```
trigger: 
 - main

pool:
   vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps: 
- task: GoTool@0
  inputs:
    version: '1.13.5'
- task: Go@0
  inputs:
    command: 'get'
    arguments: '-d'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
- task: Go@0
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
     artifactName: drop
```

Here's the error:

```
##[section]Starting: Go
==============================================================================
Task         : Go
Description  : Get, build, or test a Go application, or run a custom Go command
Version      : 0.210.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/go
==============================================================================
[command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.13.5/x64/bin/go get -d
go get .: path /home/vsts/work/1/s is not a package in module rooted at /home/vsts/work/1/s
##[error]The Go task failed with an error: Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.13.5/x64/bin/go' failed with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: Go
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
trigger: 
 - main

pool:
   vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps: 
- task: GoTool@0
  inputs:
    version: '1.13.5'
- task: Go@0
  inputs:
    command: 'get'
    arguments: '-v all'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
- task: Go@0
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
     artifactName: drop
```

Comment: That gets a little farther before failing with `build .: cannot find module for path .`.  I have a go.mod in my code so I don't know what it is complaining about.